# Escaping + symbol in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I'm having an issue with escaping the plus + symbol in `'6+ months'`. I tried the backslash but it has no effect on it.

```
function degree_of_interest()
{
    $program = $_REQUEST['degree_of_interest'];  
    $highest_level = $_REQUEST['college_1_degree'];
    $start = $_REQUEST['start_date'];

    if( !preg_match("/\A(1-2 months|3-4 months|6+ months)\Z/i",$start)
     OR !preg_match("/\A(Bachelors)\Z/i",$highest_level)
     OR !preg_match("/\A(JD \(Juris Doctor\))\Z/i",$program))
    {
        $this->errorsArray['degree_of_interest'][] = "For $program you must have a Bachelors degree";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with strings, you must obey all of the string escaping rules in addition the regex escaping rules.

That means that you must *double* escape. Your regex (as a string) should be:

```
"/\\A(1-2 months|3-4 months|6\\+ months)\\Z/i"
```